# How to boot Arch Linux after changing from AMD Radeon HD to Nvidia GTX video card?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, gpu

After swapping video cards my PC boots into Windows 7 just fine, but Arch Linux gets stuck before entering graphical mode. `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` contains some message listing all the supported AMD (aka. ATI) graphics cards, so I'm wondering if that driver doesn't fall back to generic drivers:

```
[    22.391] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI Radeon chipsets:
    ATI Radeon Mobility X600 (M24) 3150 (PCIE), ATI FireMV 2400 (PCI),
    [...]
    HAWAII, HAWAII, HAWAII, HAWAII, HAWAII
[    22.395] (++) using VT number 7

[    22.395] (EE) No devices detected.
[    22.395] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    22.395] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    22.395] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    22.395] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    22.395] (EE)
```

I tried [disabling the driver using `radeon.runpm=0`](https://askubuntu.com/a/468149/10371), but that didn't seem to help any. Is that the correct way to use a generic/fallback driver?

---

[Using the `nomodeset` option in Grub 2](https://superuser.com/questions/986875/grub2-is-it-possible-to-disable-graphics-drivers-through-kernel-boot-command) made it possible to boot into text mode, but I'm still unsure how to disable the AMD driver completely. I can't find any installed packages with `pacman --sync --search amd`.

Comment: It looks like you are still using the older xorg.config that relies on the ati graphics card. Install the new nvidia drivers and create a new xorg config file that reflects the changes. You should check the arch wiki page for the specific package that provides the drivers. 

As for creating a new xorg config file, I believe it can be done using the `nvidia-xconfig` command that comes with the drivers package.